# If $\alpha$ is an algebraic number of degree $n$, then $\alpha - 1$ is also an algebraic number of degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

If $\alpha$ is an algebraic number of degree $n$, then $\alpha - 1$ is also an algebraic number of degree $n$.

I know that if $W(x)$ is a polynomial with root $\alpha$ then $W(x+1)$ is a polynomial with root $\alpha-1$, but how show that the degree is equal.

Comment: Hint : compare the leading terms of $W(x)$ and $W(x+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1): If you expand the expression using binomial formula you can observe easily that $(x+1)^n$ and $x^n$ have the same degree.

Hint 2): A polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $p(x+1)$ is irreducible.